# Make Carbon Copy to Time Capsule?

Tags: hard-drive, time-capsule

Can I copy my entire hard drive to my time capsule?  I mean a bootable copy (carbon copy)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

1. Find an external drive (same dimension as your internal drive, preferably) and connect to your computer with USB.
2. Create a clone, with an app of your choice.
3. Disconnect and connect the drive to Time Capsule through USB.
4. Mount the drive over ATP and sync your internal hard drive to the clone with an app of your choice.
5. When failure occurs on the laptop, connect the external drive to the laptop through USB and boot.
6. And if you wish, remove the working/external hard drive from its casing, open up the laptop, and place the drive inside. If the failed drive is still usable, put it in the casing and repeat to step 1.

I have a SSD, a secondary SSD in the optical bay, and a HDD connected to Time Capstule in this configuration.

Answer (score 0):

[Unfortunately, no:](http://pondini.org/TM/Clones.html)

> Cloning via a network is problematical.  Some cloning apps won't work over a network at all, and some that do don't recommend it.  Some suggest cloning to a disk image, but since you can't boot from a disk image, you'd have to restore it somewhere first.  Worse, if the clone's on a network, you can't boot from it directly;  you must copy it somewhere that is bootable.

Create a bootable clone the traditional way (via directly connected external HDD).